# WPF Images Relative Location

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF project, inside the project I have one folder call `Images`, It contains some png and gif files. All the files in it is `Build Action= Resources` and Copy to `Output Directory = Do not copy`.

I use the following code to bind it to the Image:

```
ImageSource ImageStatus = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MPAL;component/Images/usbreader0001.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

`MPAL` is my project name and default assembly.

I have a question, where is the image compile to? Because I am able to run it whitout anay problem.

Am I calling it the right method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build Action = Resources places the image in a file named *projectname*.g.resources.  That Resource file is linked into your exe when compiled.